# Having troubles about exporting javadoc manually with eclipse AST

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt

I use eclipse AST to export javadoc. And I know there is some way to achieve. But unfortunately, I have to do myself intead of using tools with some reasons.

I have some troubles about it:

How can I get full class name instead of a simple name in typeDeclaration, methoDeclaration and fieldDeclaration(Which contains package name, eg. com.test.Test)?

**Edit**
Example code:

```
public class javaFileASTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        // read buffer from java source file
        // parse java source file and convert it into AST
        ASTParser astParser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);
        astParser.setSource(buffer.toCharArray());
        astParser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);

        CompilationUnit result = (CompilationUnit) (astParser.createAST(null));
        JavaFileAST javaFileAST = new JavaFileAST();
        result.accept(javaFileAST);

    }
}
public class JavaFileAST extends ASTVisitor {
    @Override
    public boolean visit(TypeDeclaration node) {
        // get super class 
        Type type = typeDeclaration.getSuperclassType();
        // type.toString() eg. Test
    }
}
```

Somebody helps me?

Comment: Do you want to built a java program which does that, or you do that manually?

Comment: A java program. @Ron C

Comment: In the `Class` of the type there is all the information. You can get it by writing `TheType.class` (`class` is a static field in all types)

Comment: @Ron C . It's uncorrect. Form the TypeDeclaration, I can get org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.TYPE wchich contains class type information. But unfortunately, I only get a simple name. And if use TheType.class as you show to me. I will get "org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.PrimitiveType" forever.

Comment: Can you post some example code? I don't understand how you're trying to to this.

Comment: @Ron C .I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the default interface only provides a simple name and not fully qualified name is because simple name is a textual propery, while a qualified name requires symbol resolution.

If my memory serves, there are two ways to do this.

If you only need the FQN of the top-level declared types in Java files you scan, add to your visitor a method `visit(PackageDeclaration)` and read the `package foo.bar.goo` statement, then append the package name to the simple type names. It's a hack, but it does not require symbol resolution.

If you need the FQN of each and every type you encounter, you need to activate the JDT parser symbol resolution. See the docs for `ASTParser.setResolveBindings`. Then you can call

```
ITypeBinding bind = type.resolveBinding();
String fqn = bind.getQualifiedName();
```

(Disclaimer: I wrote this from memory, I don't have a JDT project in front of me)

Comment: Can you speak detaily. For example, how to implement ICompilationUnit.